# Codeigniter foreach Undefined variable Update Data In

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want Update Data In Database Using CodeIgniter! but I have a problem

View

```
<?php foreach ($single_user as $user): ?>
```

Controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['user'] = $this->authentication->show_students();
    $data['single_user'] = $this->authentication->show_student_id($id);
```

Library

```
function show_students(){
    $query = $this->ci->db->get('users');
    $query_result = $query->result();
    return $query_result;
}
function show_student_id($data){
    $this->ci->db->select('*');
    $this->ci->db->from('users');
    $this->ci->db->where('id', $data);
    $query = $this->ci->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Have you loaded the authentication library?

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem?

Comment: I load 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('authentication');
    }

Comment: Can you please paste your URL with id and mention the base_url portion as well.

Comment: My problem is that I get an error Message: Undefined variable: single_user

Comment: Did you echo the $id = $this->uri->segment(3); and get id there? Please mention error or image.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g6avwe

Comment: <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/update_student_id1" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          method="post">

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this expression in your controller

```
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

your code must like this :

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['user'] = $this->authentication->show_students();
$data['single_user'] = $this->authentication->show_student_id($id);
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

Hopefully it helps you.